# JSON File from URL to JSON Object

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-core, url

After an API request I get a JSON file(parent) with some URLs to other JSON files(children). Is it possible to download all files and convert the children files to JSON objects in a parent file?

It is a ASP.Net Core 3.1 application written in C#.

Example Input:

```
[
    {
        "title": "AAA",
        "dates": [
            {
                "a_date": "24.09.2021",              
                "push": false,
                "date_url": "https://www-api.aaa.com/api/HEUFCCEWJHB=.json"
            },
            {
                "a_date": "27.09.2021",              
                "push": false,
                "date_url": "https://www-api.aaa.com/api/VFEWVWEWXS=.json"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "BBB",
        "dates": [
            {
                "a_date": "24.10.2021",              
                "push": false,
                "date_url": "https://www-api.aaa.com/api/HBTFDECEC=.json"
            },
            {
                "a_date": "27.10.2021",              
                "push": false,
                "date_url": "https://www-api.aaa.com/api/EWFEWIFWEW=.json"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
    [
    {
        "title": "AAA",
        "dates": [
            {
                "a_date": "24.09.2021",              
                "push": false,
                "date_url": [
                    {
                        "aa": "xx",              
                        "bb": false,
                    },
                    {
                        "aa": "zzz",              
                        "cc": true,
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "a_date": "27.09.2021",              
                "push": false,
                "date_url": [
                    {
                        "aa": "xx",              
                        "bb": false,
                    },
                    {
                        "aa": "zzz",              
                        "cc": true,
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "BBB "
        ...
    }
]
```

Optionaly:

At the end the parent JSON should be splitted in different JSON files by title.

Comment: Do you want it using `Newtonsoft.Json` or `System.Text.Json`?

Comment: Also, how should the web requests be made? Are using a particular method, do you need any custom headers?

Comment: What does your `"aa","bb","cc"` mean in your Expected Output?

Comment: @trinalbadger587 I prefer Newtonsoft.Json. Ther is a simple http request any custom headers requred.

Comment: @YiyiYou it is just a sample of the child-data

Answer (score 1):

You can try this converter:

```cs
public class UrlDownloaderConverter : JsonConverter<object>
{
    public override object Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        => JsonSerializer.Deserialize(DownloadJson(reader.GetString()), typeToConvert, options);

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        => JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, value.GetType(), options);

    public static string DownloadJson(string url)
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        using (HttpResponseMessage msg = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result)
        using (HttpContent content = msg.Content)
            return content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

[Example Usage](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PyNZI3)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is an other problem: the object-names in child-JSONs are different, so i can not map it to a Model.

Comment: @AlexanderS., I do not know what you mean. Also, I do not know `Newtonsoft.Json` so I can't help you with that.

Comment: There can be hundreds of other names in place of "aa" "bb" "cc". I can't add them all in a model.

Comment: @AlexanderS., you will have to ask that in a separate question as I do not know the context but from just what you told me I have no idea. You will probably have to write a custom converter to convert it to the object you want.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help! Now I have an idea how I can solve ist. May be I will post it later.